# Можно ли сохранить пропорции блока при изменении размера окна?

Tags: responsive, css

У меня есть круглый элемент. При изменении разрешения окна он превращается в яйцо. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы пропорции сохранились?

Answer (score 3):

Единственный элемент в HTML, который сохраняет пропорцию при изменении одной из размерностей - это img-картинка.

1) Вариант с картинкой - использовать прозрачный пиксель 1х1, ложить его в нужный блок и за счет его свойства сохранения пропорций тянуть блок.

2) Еще одна фича - это вертикальный пэддинг в процетах, значение которого считается от **ширины**.

Например, **padding-bottom: 50%** задаст блоку padding равный полу**ширине** **родителя**. Как бы странно это ни было, работает оно прекрасно:

http://jsfiddle.net/CgmeG/

Если нужны потомки внутри такого блока, то можно их повесить абсолютно на блок, так как координаты top/left/right/bottom отсчитываются от padding edge - границ padding.
Таким образом можно сделать адаптивное видео, например.

Answer (score 2):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/ZhEEG/)**

```
div {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```